# longest palindromic substring solution

Tags: python, palindrome

After completing the question on leetcode, I was reviewing other people's solutions and found that this had a crazy fast run time, but I don't fully understand the solution. Was hoping someone could explain it line by line, especially the elif statement.

From what I understand, the first if statement just checks that if you reverse the substring and it matches with the original substring that was reversed, but then I am lost with the elif.

```
class Solution:
    def longestPalindrome(self, s: str) -> str:

        if len(s) <= 1:
            return s

        i, l = 0, 0
        for j in range(len(s)):
            if s[j-l: j+1] == s[j-l: j+1][::-1]:
                i, l = j-l, l+1
                # print(s[i: i+l]) 

            elif j-l > 0 and s[j-l-1: j+1] == s[j-l-1: j+1][::-1]:
                i, l = j-l-1, l+2
                # print(s[i: i+l])

        return s[i: i+l]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given `abcNOONdeRACECAR` where `|` is the loop stepping through the string looking *back* to see if it's found a longer palindrome, and `[]` is around the best known palindrome, and the number is the length of the best known so far, it does this:

```
a|bcNOONdeRACECAR [a]bcNOONdeRACECAR 1
ab|cNOONdeRACECAR [a]bcNOONdeRACECAR 1
abc|NOONdeRACECAR [a]bcNOONdeRACECAR 1
abcN|OONdeRACECAR [a]bcNOONdeRACECAR 1
abcNO|ONdeRACECAR [a]bcNOONdeRACECAR 1
abcNOO|NdeRACECAR abcN[OO]NdeRACECAR 2
abcNOON|deRACECAR abc[NOON]deRACECAR 4
abcNOONd|eRACECAR abc[NOON]deRACECAR 4
abcNOONde|RACECAR abc[NOON]deRACECAR 4
abcNOONdeR|ACECAR abc[NOON]deRACECAR 4
abcNOONdeRA|CECAR abc[NOON]deRACECAR 4
abcNOONdeRAC|ECAR abc[NOON]deRACECAR 4
abcNOONdeRACE|CAR abc[NOON]deRACECAR 4
abcNOONdeRACEC|AR abc[NOON]deRACECAR 4
abcNOONdeRACECA|R abcNOONdeR[ACECA]R 5
abcNOONdeRACECAR| abcNOONde[RACECAR] 7
RACECAR
```

(I think the most benefit comes from the effort of trying to puzzle it out for oneself).

Things I note:

- It ends with `return s[i: i+l]` so `i` must become the start of the palindrome substring and `l` must become its length.
- `for j in range(len(s))` j steps through the string from left to right and does not go backwards; this code finds the answer in one-pass over the string.
- The branching is `if/elif` which means there's a missing `else` which is where "I have not found a palindrome right now, do nothing" happens.
- There are commented out print statements which show the current best candidate palindrome substring, which help show how it works, adding the `else` and printing in there might help.
- Palindromes can be even length `"gg"`, `"toot"` or odd length `"a"`, `"lol"`, `"racecar"`. You can increase the length of a palindrome by +1 or +2. The `if` and `elif` are these cases, add one to the right and see if it's a longer palindrome, add one to the left and one to the right and see if it's a longer palindrome.
- The tests in the code do `j-l` a lot, which we see is the current position in the string, minus the length of the best known palindrome. i.e. the index `j` is considered to be *at the end of the possible palindrome, looking backwards.

Starting at the beginning `s[j-l: j+1]` is 0-0 to 0+1 which is the first character. One character is a palindrome, so start and length are updated `i, l = j-l, l+1` this is now the best known candidate.

j moves on to index 1. Now the test `s[j-l: j+1]` is asking "looking back from this position, the length of the best known palindrome and one-char forward, is there a 2 character palindrome ending at the second character?".

The elif test `s[j-l-1: j+1]` looks back one character further, as long as that doesn't go back past the beginning of the string, `j-l > 0`.

If it finds that it's on the end of a longer palindrome than the best known, it updates start `i` and length `l` to be the current one.

Otherwise, `j` moves on one char into the string. As j moves one further, the palindrome can only grow by length 1 or 2, it can't go +5 in one move. So either the palindrome grows +1 palindrome or +2, or we've moved past a palindrome and out into unknown territory. In unknown territory we're only looking for longer palindromes than the best known, not starting from 1 again.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of comments, whoever wrote the code didn't comment it!

Answer (score -1):

```
def check_palindrome(inp):
    ot = []
    n = len(inp) - 1
    while n >= 0:
        ot.append(inp[n])
        n = n - 1
    ot_stg = ''.join(ot)
    if inp == ot_stg:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def palindrome_substring(inp):
    n = len(inp)
    pal_str = ""
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            if inp[i] == inp[j]:
                sub_str = inp[i:j+1]
                if check_palindrome(sub_str) and len(pal_str) < len(sub_str):
                    pal_str = sub_str
    return pal_str
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is wrong. The author asked for an explanation on how a certain piece of code works. Your answer does not explain how the code they asked about is works, neither it presents a source code that actually works.